# Which method should I use for this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

this is my first time doing calculus so I do not have a good book to study.. Any recommendations?

$$ y' =\sqrt{x + y + 8} $$

Comment: Are you asking this question on how to solve the ODE or you want recommendations on books?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif both would be great but a book is better than a particular case!

Comment: Internet is a valuable source of informations, I learned a lot just by searching the internet and especially MATH SE ^^

Comment: Thank a lot @OussamaBoussif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try to make a substitution, set $h(x)=y+x$, differentiate this function with respect to $x$, then you should obtain: $\frac {dh}{dx} -1 = \sqrt{h(x) + 8}$ then you can apply the common separation of variables.

Answer (score 1):

> $$ y' =\sqrt{x + y + 8} $$

Hint:

$\nu(x):=y(x)+x$

$$\frac{d\nu (x)}{dx}-1=\sqrt{\nu (x)+8}$$

Solve for $\frac{d \nu}{dx}$:

$$\frac{d \nu (x)}{dx}=\sqrt{\nu (x)+8}+1$$

Divide both sides by $\sqrt{\nu (x)+8}+1$:

$$\frac{\frac{d \nu (x)}{dx}}{\sqrt{\nu (x)+8}+1}=1$$

I hope that you can finish from here